# NGINX: add_before_body with .php

Tags: windows-server-2008, nginx, php, configuration

```
worker_processes 8;

events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
    gzip off;
    root htdocs;
    add_before_body subsites/dropletlocal/library/global/func-global.class.php; #DOESN'T
    add_before_body subsites/dropletlocal/library/global/test.html; #WORKS
    include mime.types;
    include web-hosting/*.conf;
}
```

Hello, I'm trying to implement the function add_before_body with a .php file, however it gives the error "No input file specified". Furthermore when I use a .html file it will include it fine. 
I'd really appreciate any help.

Example .conf;

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  ***.es.vc;
    location / {
        root   htdocs/subsites/***;
        index  index.php;
    }
    location ~ \.php$ {
        root   htdocs/subsites/***;
        fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include        fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you have in server config about php?

Comment: Amended question and added an example server.conf.

Comment: For me it looks wrong to have `subsites` part in `root` and in `add_before_body`

Comment: I've adjusted the root and now it wont load any .php files at all.

Comment: Well, then probably you should change `add_before_body`…

Comment: I've tried that. Still the same error.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21683/discussion-between-user3902523-and-alexey-ten).